# replace specific fields in file with fields from other file,fields which needs to be replaced will be found by matching different fields of samefiles

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed, nawk

I want to replace specific fields in file (separated by ,) with fields from other file
Fields which needs to be replaced will be found after matching different fields of same files.
e.g.

```
cat test1.dat

12345,98765,aaaa,bbbbb

12346,98766,cccc,ddddd



cat test2.dat 
12345,something,something,something,something,something,98765,something,something,somethi
12345,something,something,something,something,something,45655,something,something,somethi
12346,something,something,something,something,something,98766,something,something,somethi
12346,something,something,something,something,something,44556,something,something,something
```

**Output file**

```
cat test3.dat
aaaa,something,something,something,something,something,bbbbb,something,something,somethi
12345,something,something,something,something,something,45655,something,something,somethi
cccc,something,something,something,something,something,ddddd,something,something,somethi
12346,something,something,something,something,something,44556,something,something,somethi
```

in above example we are checking

```
if ($1 of test2.dat == $1 of test1.dat && $7 of test2.dat == $2 of test1.dat )
then

($1 of test2.dat = $3 of test1.dat) 

($7 of test2.dat = $4 of test1.dat)
```

test1.dat will have distinct values of $1 and $2

test2.dat will be a huge file having millions of records

I am looking for solution which is fastest (we can even iterate through test1.dat and check for each row in test3.dat if it is fastest solution)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

assumes file1 has unique keys

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=","}       # set delimiters
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0; next}   # store file1 in array
       $1 in a {split(a[$1],b);   # if the key exists in file1, set file1 values in b
                if($7==b[2])      # and seventh field matches, replace values; print
                  {$7=b[4]; $1=b[3]}}1' file1 file2
```

gives this

```
aaaa,something,something,something,something,something,bbbbb,something,something,somethi
12345,something,something,something,something,something,45655,something,something,somethi
cccc,something,something,something,something,something,ddddd,something,something,somethi
12346,something,something,something,something,something,44556,something,something,something
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;b[$1,$2]=$4;next} (($1,$7) in a){val=$7;$7=b[$1,$7];$1=a[$1,val]} 1' OFS=, test1.dat test2.dat
```

Output will be as follows.

```
aaaa,something,something,something,something,something,bbbbb,something,something,somethi
12345,something,something,something,something,something,45655,something,something,somethi
cccc,something,something,something,something,something,ddddd,something,something,somethi
12346,something,something,something,something,something,44556,something,something,something
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate an `awk` script from `test1.dat`, then run that script against `test2.dat`. Perhaps it would be faster than running a two-dimentional-check `awk`. Example, this command:

```
awk -F, '{print "if(\$1==\""$1"\" && \$7==\""$2"\"){\$1=\""$3"\"; \$7=\""$4"\"};"}' test1.dat
```

would generate the needed `awk` code, which looks like:

```
if($1=="12345" && $7=="98765"){$1="aaaa"; $7="bbbbb"};
if($1=="12346" && $7=="98766"){$1="cccc"; $7="ddddd"};
```

---

Test:

```
$ codes=$(awk -F, '{print "if(\$1==\""$1"\" && \$7==\""$2"\"){\$1=\""$3"\"; \$7=\""$4"\"};"}' test1.dat)
$ echo "$codes" "print;"
if($1=="12345" && $7=="98765"){$1="aaaa"; $7="bbbbb"};
if($1=="12346" && $7=="98766"){$1="cccc"; $7="ddddd"}; print;

$ awk -F, -f <(echo "{$codes" "print;}") test2.dat
aaaa something something something something something bbbbb something something somethi
12345,something,something,something,something,something,45655,something,something,somethi
cccc something something something something something ddddd something something somethi
12346,something,something,something,something,something,44556,something,something,something
```